# error while passing list containing strings

Tags: python, list, parameters

Sorry I am still a newbie. Trying to learn python !!
my code-

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count=0
    for item in x:
        if x[item]=="fizz":


             count=count+1
    return count
```

gives me an error when I try to pass `fizz_count(['fizz', 'buzz'])`-

> list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Just change `if x[item]=="fizz"` with `if item=="fizz"`

Comment: What fred said; `item` is each element of `x` not each index; for future reference you could use `return x.count("fizz")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count=0
    for item in range(len(x)):
        if x[item]=="fizz":
            count=count+1
    return count
```

or

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count=0
    for item in x:
        if item=="fizz":
            count=count+1
    return count
```

Comment: The second version being the RightOne(tm) - well, the one first does work but is unpythonic, inefficient, and will only accept subscriptable containers while  the second works with just any iterable.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I'd spent more time getting to know the standard library when I was first learning!

```
import collections

word_count = collections.Counter(['fizz', 'buzz'])

print(word_count['fizz'])
```